# Why does Cm_RedisSession Seems to Disable `session_decode`

Tags: session, cm-redissession

I'm running a Magento 1.9 system, and have `Cm_RedisSession` configured to store my sessions in a local redis instance.  For reasons that aren't entirely clear to me, it seems like the `session_decode` function no longer works.

The `session_decode` function is supposed to accept a session encoded string, and automatically populate the `$_SESSIONS` array with the data.  I'm working on a project where this is necessary.  When I'm using files or databases to save the sessions, my function works as expected.  However, with `Cm_RedisSession` active, it doesn't.

Does anyone know, (or can think of a reason), why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really bizarre bug.  I didn't find the reason for it, but it the bug was only present when I called `session_decode` **from certain methods**.  I'm going to write this one off as a PHP bug specific to the version my client is running (something something race condition/redis sessions) but leave the question open in case a wizard stumbles in.

Comment: Hi Alan, have you found a solution for this matter in the meantime?

Comment: @Max If doing less Magento work is a solution, then yes.  Otherwise, no, I never really got to the bottom of this or came up with a work around.